# Use a different matplotlibrc for savefig

Tags: matplotlib, themes, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook, with a `matplotlibrc` style that's consistent with its theme set using `jupyterthemes`.  That plotting style however does not look good if I want to export it to PNG to use it within my other documents.

How do I specify a different `matplotlibrc` when I do a `savefig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most matplotlib style settings are applied at the moment the object they apply to is created.
You would hence need to create two different plots, one with the usual style of your notebook and another one with the style from the style file. The latter one would be the one to save.

A decent solution would be to create a plot in a function. You can then call this function within a context, `with plt.style.context(<your style>):` to give the figure a different style.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([2,3,4], label="label")
    ax.legend()

# Plot with general style of the notebook    
plot()

# Plot with your chosen style for saved figures
with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
    plot()
    plt.savefig("dark.png")
    #plt.close(plt.gcf()) # if you don't want to show this figure on screen

plt.show()
```

[image]

Relevant here: The [matplotlib customizing](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing `matplotlib/__init__.py` reveals a number of functions used for managing `rcParams`. To update `rcParams` from a file, use [`matplotlib.rc_file`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L1279):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rc_file('/tmp/matplotlibrc')
plt.plot([0,1], [0,10])
plt.savefig('/tmp/out.png')
```

with `/tmp/matplotlibrc` containing

```
lines.linewidth   : 10     # line width in points
lines.linestyle   : --     # dashed line
```

yields
[image]

---

PS. In hindsight, having found `rc_file`, googling shows it is documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_file).